# Conversion of height "feet'inches" for an entire column to decimal height in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R and am currently trying to convert an entire column of different heights in the "feet'inches" format into feet.decimal format.  I have been trying to utilize gsub in order to do this byt have had no luck.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you show us what you've tried? Also, this question has nothing to do with Rstudio, so I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cut:

```r
heights <- function(s) {
  vec <- lapply(strsplit(s, "'"), as.numeric)
  stopifnot(all(lengths(vec) < 3))
  sapply(vec, function(v) sum(v / c(1, 12)[seq_along(v)]))
}
heights(c("5'0", "5'1", "6'0", "6'", "6", "5'13", "oops"))
# Warning in lapply(strsplit(s, "'"), as.numeric) :
#   NAs introduced by coercion
# [1] 5.000000 5.083333 6.000000 6.000000 6.000000 6.083333       NA
```